# Block access to subdirectory with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

How to block all subdirectories with .htaccess ?

I have:

```
/
/subdir
/subdir/file_1
/subdir/file_2
```

and want to deny acces to

```
/subdir
```

yet to maintain full access to

```
/
/subdir/file_1
/subdir/file_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^subdir/? - [F]
```

The RewriteCond is just a little extra insurance.

Apache's rewrite_module must be activated.

Comment: Is there a way to automaticly deny all subdirs? They are created kinda dynamicly.

Comment: Remove the trailing $ in the RewriteRule regexp to block subdirs as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 12.34.56.78
```

Source : [Here](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/htaccess-deny-from-all-restrict-directory-access.html)

Comment: This one works as well. And was better for me at least.